# String extraction confusion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developeing one windows application.

In that, i am uploading one file from any path on the computer.

From that i want to just get the file name.

I have used >> `string name = openFileDialog1.FileName;` for that.

I am getting the file name with compleate path of that. means result is as follows>>

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\15030000.md"
```

15030000.md is my file name. I just want to extract first 4 characters out of it.
i.e. 1503 [ As it indicates date and month ].

For that i tried `substring` function. But later realised that full path can be any thing. I cant use substring function for extraction of `1503` out of `"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\15030000.md"`

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) to get the file name and later you can use [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) or [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to get first 4 characters.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
string firstFourCharacters = fileName.Take(4);
//Or 
//Check if the fileName.Length >= 4
string firstFourCharacters = fileName.Substring(0,4);
```

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` in your using statements on the top of page

Comment: Make sure you add `using System.Linq` in your using statements, this will let LINQ extension methods to be available for your current code.

Comment: @PakkPuneriPorag, you can use `Substring` or `Take`, with Substring you have to check the length to avoid the exception if the filename length is less that 4 characters.